# Monitor location provider access on android without root?

Tags: android

Is there a way to monitor which app or when an app asks a location provider for the current position without having root access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry. With the `PASSIVE_PROVIDER`, you can determine that somebody else is asking for fixes as those fixes come in, but you have no way to know what apps are asking for them.